# Is R Sandwich package not generating the expected clustered robust standard errors?

Tags: r, package, cluster-computing, linear-regression, robust

## Load data

`utils::data("InstInnovation", package = "sandwich")`

`df <- InstInnovation`

## Create group variable combining 'company' and 'year'

`df[['cluster_var']] <- factor(paste0(df$company,"-",df$year))`

## Linear regression model

`model <- lm(sales ~ competition + log(capital/employment) + year, data = df)`

## Why this:

`lmtest::coeftest(model, vcov = vcovCL(model, type="HC3", cluster=~company+year))`

## Produces Standard Errors DIFFERENT than this?

`lmtest::coeftest(model, vcov = vcovCL(model, type="HC3", cluster=~cluster_var))`

Shouldn't `cluster=~company+year` and `cluster=~cluster_var` be equivalent?

In addition, I cannot find a place (e.g. Github) to report issues on R sandwich package, I found this but is just a read-only mirror: https://github.com/cran/sandwich

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cluster=~company+year` is indeed something different: 'multiway clustering'. I found the explanation here:

http://fmwww.bc.edu/repec/bost10/BOS10.baum.pdf

https://francish.netlify.app/post/note-on-robust-standard-errors/